How to remove the column highlighting when using columnFormats?
I am using columnFormats() to format a column as a date:
public function columnFormats(): array
{
    return [
        'C' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY
    ];
}

But it also highlights the formatted column on the exported excel file whenever it's first opened:

Is it possible to remove this highlighting?

can you try in the end of excel to $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1');

@francisco thank you, do you know where I should put it? I tried the following which did not work: public function registerEvents(): array     {         return [             AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {                 $event->sheet->getCell('A1');             },         ];     }

@francisco, I did it, I used: $event->sheet->setSelectedCells('A1'); instead! thank you

If anyone ever encounters this in the future, this is how I solved it:
public function registerEvents(): array {
    return [
        AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {                 
            $event->sheet->setSelectedCells('A1');
         },
    ];
}

I select the first cell in the sheet and it removes the highlighting
